# move all files and folders in a folder to another?

Tags: php, windows

I want to move all files and folders inside a folder to another folder. I found a code to copy all files inside a folder to another folder. 
[move all files in a folder to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608450/using-scandir-to-find-folders-in-a-directory-php)

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("source");
// Identify directories
$source = "source/";
$destination = "destination/";
// Cycle through all source files
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    $delete[] = $source.$file;
  }
}
// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ($delete as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

How do I change this to move all folders and files inside this folder to another folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy all files and folder from one directory to another directory PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513618/copy-all-files-and-folder-from-one-directory-to-another-directory-php)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is what i use

```
   // Function to remove folders and files 
    function rrmdir($dir) {
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            $files = scandir($dir);
            foreach ($files as $file)
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rrmdir("$dir/$file");
            rmdir($dir);
        }
        else if (file_exists($dir)) unlink($dir);
    }

    // Function to Copy folders and files       
    function rcopy($src, $dst) {
        if (file_exists ( $dst ))
            rrmdir ( $dst );
        if (is_dir ( $src )) {
            mkdir ( $dst );
            $files = scandir ( $src );
            foreach ( $files as $file )
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                    rcopy ( "$src/$file", "$dst/$file" );
        } else if (file_exists ( $src ))
            copy ( $src, $dst );
    }
```

Usage

```
    rcopy($source , $destination );
```

Another example without deleting destination file or folder

```
    function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
        $dir = opendir($src); 
        @mkdir($dst); 
        while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
            if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
                if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                    recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
                } 
                else { 
                    copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        closedir($dir); 
    }
```

Please See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php for more juicy examples

Thanks
:)

Comment: I know this is old post but still - dont you need to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of '/' for system compatibility?

Answer (score 19):

Use [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) instead of `copy`.

Unlike the C function with the same name, `rename` can move a file from one file system to another (since PHP 4.3.3 on Unix and since PHP 5.3.1 on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time to answer for the problem ...but i sure it is not relevant with the issue ..your answer only work for **files** and not for folder.

Comment: Beware is trying to use `rename` from different disks (ex: EC2 to EFS) as PHP will throw a "copy" error as seen in this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54097

Answer (score 12):

Think this should do the trick:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

```
shell_exec("mv sourcedirectory path_to_destination");
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This will work on Linux machines but not on Windows and as far as I can see the original question is tagged as windows. So at best it can work on Linux - but to make it work on Windows you need to change "mv" command with Windows' counterpart "move".

Answer (score 12):

You need the custom function:

```
Move_Folder_To("./path/old_folder_name",   "./path/new_folder_name");
```

function code:

```
function Move_Folder_To($source, $target){
    if( !is_dir($target) ) mkdir(dirname($target),null,true);
    rename( $source,  $target);
}
```

Comment: This work only if the parent path exists. For example `rename( "./path/old_folder_name",  "./NEWpath/new_folder_name" );` doesn't work. In this case you should create the dir with `mkdir(dirname("./NEWpath/new_folder_name"),null,true);`

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers are not complete for me, beacuse *DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR* are not defined on any answer (thans to [Edgar Aivars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5328124/edgars-aivars) for remember that!), but I want to write my solution for move (rename), copy and delete directory structures (based on this post info, the credits are for yours!).

```
defined('DS') ? NULL : define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

function full_move($src, $dst){
    full_copy($src, $dst);
    full_remove($src);
}

function full_copy($src, $dst) {
    if (is_dir($src)) {
        @mkdir( $dst, 0777 ,TRUE);
        $files = scandir($src);
        foreach($files as $file){
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                full_copy("$src".DS."$file", "$dst".DS."$file");
            }
        }
    } else if (file_exists($src)){
        copy($src, $dst);
    }
}

function full_remove($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files as $file){
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                full_remove("$dir".DS."$file");
            }
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }else if (file_exists($dir)){
        unlink($dir);
    }
}
```

I hope this hepls anyone! (lile me in the future :D )

**EDIT**: Spell corrections... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$src = 'user_data/company_2/T1/';
$dst = 'user_data/company_2/T2/T1/';

rcopy($src, $dst);  // Call function 
// Function to Copy folders and files       
function rcopy($src, $dst) {
    if (file_exists ( $dst ))
        rrmdir ( $dst );
    if (is_dir ( $src )) {
        mkdir ( $dst );
        $files = scandir ( $src );
        foreach ( $files as $file )
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
                rcopy ( "$src/$file", "$dst/$file" );

    } else if (file_exists ( $src ))
        copy ( $src, $dst );
                    rrmdir ( $src );
}       

// Function to remove folders and files 
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files as $file)
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rrmdir("$dir/$file");
        rmdir($dir);
    }
    else if (file_exists($dir)) unlink($dir);
}
```

Comment: Nice this works.. I didn't have to refactor this code :)

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at a recursive move function, after days of research and going through other excellent examples out there.

It provides for an `overwriteExisting` flag for choice. Consequently, if the `overwriteExisting` flag is `false`, the file will not be moved and the folder containing the file would not be removed.

```
function moveRecursive($sourcePath, $targetPath, $overwriteExisting) {
    clearstatcache(); // not sure if this helps, or is even required.
    $dir = opendir($sourcePath);
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        echo nl2br($file . "\n");
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if (is_dir($sourcePath . "/" . $file) == true) {
                if (is_dir($targetPath. "/" . $file) == false) {
                    // I believe rename would be faster than copying and unlinking.
                    rename($sourcePath . "/" . $file, $targetPath. "/" . $file);
                } else {
                    moveRecursive($sourcePath . "/" . $file, $targetPath ."/" . $file, $overwriteExisting);
                    if ($files = glob($sourcePath . "/*")) {
                        // remove the empty directory.
                        if (@rmdir($sourcePath . "/" . $file) == false) {
                            echo nl2br("rmdir has not removed empty directory " . $sourcePath . "/" . $file . "\n");
                        }
                    } else {
                        // when overwriteExisting flag is false, there would be some files leftover.
                        echo nl2br("cannot remove. not empty, count = " . count(glob($sourcePath . "/*")) . " -> " . $sourcePath . "/" . $file . "\n");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (file_exists($targetPath. "/" . $file)) {
                    if ($overwriteExisting == true) {
                        // overwrite the file.
                        rename($sourcePath . "/" . $file, $targetPath. "/" . $file);
                    }
                } else {
                    // if the target file does not exist, simply move the file.
                    rename($sourcePath . "/" . $file, $targetPath. "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

I have spent about 3 hours testing this in many different scenarios, and it works most of the time. Although, sometimes, it gives me an `Access denied code(5)` error on Windows, which I have been unable to figure out. This is why I have put the `clearstatcache()` function up at the top, after reading up on its documentation. I don't know whether this is its appropriate usage. I can definitely imagine that it would slow down the function.

I can also imagine that this method may be faster than the `copy -> unlink` cycle, because if a target sub-folder does not exist, the whole folder tree below would be just moved. However, I am not sure and don't have the experience to conduct exhaustive tests, yet.

Comment: You deserve 10 upvotes, not just one. _thank you_ for sharing this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I use it

```
// function used to copy full directory structure from source to target
function full_copy( $source, $target )
{
    if ( is_dir( $source ) )
    {
        mkdir( $target, 0777 );
        $d = dir( $source );

        while ( FALSE !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) )
        {
            if ( $entry == '.' || $entry == '..' )
            {
                continue;
            }

            $Entry = $source . '/' . $entry;           
            if ( is_dir( $Entry ) )
            {
                full_copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
                continue;
            }
            copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
        }

        $d->close();

    } else {
        copy( $source, $target );
    }
}
```